# How to rotate floating action button without rotating shadow?

Tags: android, rotation, android-animation, floating-action-button

I rotate the FAB in such a simple way:

```
fab.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate));
```

*rotate.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

This works, but together with the FAB its shadow rotates. But I need only the FAB to rotate (or even its src image, if there's any difference).

Comment: My solution with rotating ImageView over FAB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426138/rotating-floatingactionbutton/33169100#33169100

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Did you try with the animate method provided by the Compat library? I too had the same problem when using Animation utils

```
final OvershootInterpolator interpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
ViewCompat.animate(fab).
           rotation(135f).
           withLayer().
           setDuration(300).
           setInterpolator(interpolator).
           start();
```

Comment: This is still rotate shadow

Comment: and introduce a strange shadow clipping too!

Comment: works ok with design support lib 23.2.0! no shadow rotation (tested on 6.0, 4.4).
OvershootInterpolator is cool :)

Comment: Tested with latest support lib 24.1.1 and its working fine. on Android  4.4.4 Samsung Neo, and Android 5.0.1 Micromax Bolt

Comment: How can I set the rotation of the icon within the fab, instead of animating it?

Comment: how to make this animation repeats?

Answer (score 21):

```
public void rotateFabForward() {
    ViewCompat.animate(fab)
            .rotation(135.0F)
            .withLayer()
            .setDuration(300L)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(10.0F))
            .start();
}

public void rotateFabBackward() {
    ViewCompat.animate(fab)
            .rotation(0.0F)
            .withLayer()
            .setDuration(300L)
            .setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(10.0F))
            .start();
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. How can I achieve the same, but without animation? Meaning I want to set the rotation right away?

Comment: set duration to 0L

Answer (score 5):

Shortest way:
For clockwise rotation:

```
fab.animate().rotationBy(135f) // 135f = 135 degree.
```

For anticlockwise rotation (reset to initial position):

```
fab.animate().rotationBy(-135f) // 135f = 135 degree.
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an entirely another approach that works flawlessly for me (the one suggested in the accepted answer produces a clipped shadow on pre-L). Create an XML drawable and wrap your FAB icon into a `<rotate>` tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="45">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>
</rotate>
```

Set this drawable to your FAB, and animate either its level directly or the `imageLevel` property of the FAB itself; it goes from 0 to 10000. If you'd like an `OvershootInterpolator`, then set `toDegrees` to 90 and animate the level up to the value of 5000 so it doesn't go beyond the bounds.

Comment: side note: if drawable is vector, you cannot use bitmap, instead you might give it a try following:  `<rotate drawable="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can just rotate 45 degrees to get the cancel button effect on the tap of the fab button and rotate again -45 to get it normal.

```
binding?.fabAddPostMenu?.animate()?.rotationBy(45f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Same can be achieved via object animator:

```
  moveRight.rotation = -180f
```