# onClickListener for the touch outside of the popupWindow

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

From the question [Issue dismissing popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577596/issue-dismissing-popup-window) I learned how to hide the `popupWindow` (before this, `popupWindow.dismiss();` in the following code didn't work).

```
private void initFAB(){
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        boolean showPopupWindow = false;

        public void onClick(View view) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupWindowContent = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window_content, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupWindowContent,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            if (!showPopupWindow){
                rotateFabForward();

                View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //...
                    }
                };

                // ...

                popupWindow.showAtLocation(fab, Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM, 50, 400);
                showPopupWindow = true;
            }
            else{
                rotateFabBackward();
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                showPopupWindow = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, when I click outside the `popupWindow` and it disappears, `FloatingActionButton` don't rotates back (it has `+` icon when the `popupWindow` is hidden and rotates 45 degress and icon becomes `×` when the `popupWindow` is visible).

Any listeners that allows to registry the touch outside the `popupWindow` and execute `rotateFabBackward()`?

---

P. S. Also, thanks for the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562333/how-to-rotate-floating-action-button-without-rotaing-shadow) question about FAB rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add onDismiss listener like that

```
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        rotateFabBackward();
        showPopupWindow = false;
        // end may TODO anything else                   
    }
});
```