# FloatingActionButton rotation

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

I have a FloatingActionButton that I want to make rotate while synchronizing data with an AsyncTask.

But before using the AsyncTask, my problem is making the FAB rotate at all.

Here are the involved parts of my code :

```
public void refreshAccountInfo(){
    /*Synchronization logic*/
    FloatingActionButton button = ButterKnife.findById(getActivity(), R.id.floating_action_button);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.clockwise);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    button.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

**clockwise.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:fromDegrees="360"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    </rotate>
</set>
```

I have found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426138/rotating-floatingactionbutton) with the same issue but since the only answer isn't satisfying or understandable at all I make this thread of mine.

Comment: "FAB rotate at all" - please explain.

Comment: I can't make the FAB to rotate in the first place (aka before using the animation with the AsyncTask)